# Combining multiple features in a classification task

Tags: classification, matlab

This question is a little general, but I am looking for suggestions of a method. I have several images that contain images of animals and I have to characterize which animals they are, let's call them anm1 and anm2 (there are only 2 options). In order to do that I have written 4 different methods to characterize them in MATLAB (m1 m2 m3 m4). The different methods I am using are not important (they use different geometrical characteristics and they are independent of each other) but some of the methods are very accurate and some have several false positives/negatives.

The way we classify is this: we are assuming in method1 that we have a cutoff1. If a geometrical index is over cutoff1 then it is anm1, if it is lower it is anm2. Some methods are more accurate which means that there less wrong characterizations of animals (the characterization is purely geometrical no regression or machine learning used). We have several animals on the images (up to 15),and some methods accurately identify all but 2 of them(i consider that pretty accurate) and others identify all but 4 or 6 of them which is not a good result.The different methods are examining different features of the image so I can not use just one of them.

I want to use all 4 tests to characterize the animals so I am hoping to find a way to put weights on the different methods (so that I know which one to 'trust' more), so that I can use all four to give me the accurate characterization. I was wondering if anyone has a suggestion about what kind of test/technique to use.I am using MATLAB to do the analysis.

Thank you.

Comment: Do each of your 4 methods give you a predicted probability for anm1, eg? If so, why not build a model that takes those 4 probs as inputs?

Comment: @gung No, they do not give me probability, they just give me whether the shape is 1 or 2.I have some geometric criteria and if they are over that criteria it is anm1 and if they are under they are anm2.

Comment: Do you know the uncertainty of each method, i.e., do you know the likelihood? Also, are the results of these methods independent?

Comment: @Memming: The 4 methods are independent of each other. There is no uncertainty on the methods. Based on empirical data we have a threshold that determines whether we have anm1 or anm2.

Comment: @ALB I don't think you understood what I meant exactly. I was going to suggest optimal Bayesian combination of information. To do so, each source of information needs to be described probabilistically. You mention that some of them are very accurate, which I interpreted as having a small uncertainty, but maybe that's not what you meant...

Comment: @Memming: sorry it seems that i misunderstood. What I meant is this. Assuming in method1 I have a cutoff1. If a geometrical index is over cutoof1 then it is anm1, if it is lower it is anm2. Some methods are more accurate meaning that there  less mischaracterizations of animals. We have several animals on the images (up to 15),and some methods accurately identify all but 2 of them(i consider that pretty accurate) and others identify all but 4 or 6 of them which is not a good result. I would like to put weights in each method so i know which one i can 'trust' more.

Comment: @ALB so you want to combine classifiers. There are many ways to do so (including Bayesian approaches). Please update the question with those details.

Comment: @Memming: i updated the question. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: @ALB still not enough information. Can you tell us about the architecture of your classifiers? I don't know if Ensemble learning (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) applies or you just need to make a single bigger classifier with all the features....

Comment: @Memming: I am not sure I understand the question. I am not using neural networks or anything like that to classify the shapes. It is a simple cutoff that is used, if it is over it is '1' if it is under it is '2'.

Comment: You should focus on having an accurate method rather than combining accurate and inaccurate methods. Just reject inaccurate methods and combine features of accurate methods to have one best method. It may be useful if you can post some sample data here.

Comment: Why don't you use a standard multi-feature classification algorithm?

Comment: Can I get a reference for this recommendation? I am using Matlab but an generic example on how to use this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining several predictions to get a better prediction is called stacking. In your case you could consider a logistic regression model to combine the predictions. For more information see stacking on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning